# Is there anyway to bind an attribute when that attribute is already being specified?

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core

I'm trying to use Vue.js in an ASP.NET Core app. I have certain tag helpers being used on page that add HTML attributes of their own, and in some instances, I need to add a `v-bind` to the same attribute. However, when I do this, the explicitly defined attribute always wins out over the `v-bind`. For example:

```
<span v-bind:id="foo"></span>
```

On a regular element, Vue would render this as something like:

```
<span id="foo"></span>
```

Pretty straight-forward stuff. However, the tag helper let's say adds its own `id`, so the pre-Vue processed HTML would look like:

```
<span id="bar" v-bind:id="foo"></span>
```

When Vue processes this, the result is:

```
<span id="bar"></span>
```

Granted, this is a pretty obvious edge-case. If everything was being coded by hand, you'd never actually include both. Nevertheless, it seems like there should be someway to have the `v-bind` override. Is there something I'm missing or anyone have any bright ideas how I can work around this?

**EDIT**

Sorry folks. I guess I didn't make this as clear as it should be.

1. `id` here is just an example. This is not a CSS thing. I can't "just use `class`, instead". I need to be able to bind to the necessary attribute.
2. The problem is that I'm not in control of the attribute that's coming in. My actual code doesn't have the attribute, just `v-bind:attribute`. The tag helper is adding the attribute in addition to my `v-bind`, and I just want my `v-bind` to take precedence rather than the attribute itself.

Comment: @KirkLarkin: That's interesting. I didn't try this on its own (my fault, I should have), but I can confirm the source contains `<span id="bar" v-bind:id="foo"></span>`, i.e. it's not something like the tag helper is removing my `v-bind` or something. It's there, and once the response has been returned, ASP.NET Core is out of the picture. Not sure what the exact difference would be between what I have and what you created in a jsfiddle, but that at least gives me a path to tease out the difference.

Comment: Well, I haven't updated to the latest patch (running 2.5.16 vs 2.5.17 current). Not sure if that makes a difference, but I can certain try to update and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Your question basically boils down to this: Some server-side application renders a HTML tag inside a Vue template that has both an explicitly set attribute and a `v-bind` on the same attribute. It does not matter what produces this code, so the question is actually not related to ASP.NET Core, it only matters that the same attribute is used twice. And now you want Vue to replace the explicitly set attribute with its bound value.

This is actually what Vue will do when an element already defines an attribute and it has some value to bind to that element. The same applies to components where the documentation even [explains this in some way](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Replacing-Merging-with-Existing-Attributes). That section also explains the value merging that happens for some the `class` and `style` attributes:

> For most attributes, the value provided to the component will replace the value set by the component. So for example, passing `type="text"` will replace `type="date"` and probably break it! Fortunately, the `class` and `style` attributes are a little smarter, so both values are merged, making the final value: `form-control date-picker-theme-dark`.

Anyway, if you run this Snippet, you can see that Vue indeed replaces the value that was originally set in the value when it is binding the value:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    foo: 'baz',
  },
});

// show rendered HTML
document.getElementById('pre').addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.textContent = app.$el.innerHTML;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <span id="bar" v-bind:id="foo">Foo bar baz</span>
</div>

<pre id="pre">(Click here to show the innerHTML of the app)</pre>
```